# Angular 8 how to build an app with a different environment

Tags: angular

It seems after recently upgrading from angular 7 to angular 8 my app does not build properly with different environments.

For example i want to build using the test environment.

```
npm run build --configuration=test
```

**angular.json**

```
"configurations": {
                "production": {
                    "index": "src/production/index.html",
                    "optimization": true,
                    "outputHashing": "all",
                    "sourceMap": false,
                    "extractCss": true,
                    "namedChunks": false,
                    "aot": true,
                    "extractLicenses": true,
                    "vendorChunk": false,
                    "buildOptimizer": true,
                    "fileReplacements": [
                        {
                            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "test": {
                    "index": "src/test/index.html",
                    "optimization": true,
                    "outputHashing": "all",
                    "sourceMap": false,
                    "extractCss": true,
                    "namedChunks": false,
                    "aot": true,
                    "extractLicenses": true,
                    "vendorChunk": false,
                    "buildOptimizer": true,
                    "fileReplacements": [
                        {
                            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                            "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

However this doesen;'t work and reverts back to the default environment file.

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    build: 'Local',
    ...
};
```

**environment.test.ts**

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    build: 'Test',
    ...
};
```

Comment: Pretty sure you ran the wrong command `npm run build --configuration=test` should be using angular cli's command `ng build --configuration=test`

Comment: check your `package.json` file npm run build is the same as ng build.

Comment: Yah but you gotta understand that, running the script from package.json is not the same as running `ng build --configuration=test`. The package.json contains preset of scripts, in your case for `build` is `ng build`. Which means you can't just send additional args with out using `--` so `npm run build -- --configuration=test` would be the same as `ng build --configuration=test`

Answer (score 0):

`ng build --configuration=test` should work. We use the same setup.

Consider the output path in `angular.json` (under: projects > your-project > architect > build > options > outputPath).